# Cómo consultar dos campos e imprimirlos en un una fila

Tags: php, html, mysql

Saludos, tengo dos columnas y quiero imprimir los resultados de las dos columnas  en una sola variable, aquí está mi código:

```html
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'master3.1416');
  mysql_select_db('roda', $con);

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM caso ORDER BY id_bl DESC " ,$con);

  $contar = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($contar == 0){

  }else{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $row['id_bl'];
      $row['bl'];

?>
  <option value='<?php echo $row["id_bl"], $row["bl"]; ?>' required></option>
<?php  
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué ocurre con tu código, aparte de usar una extensión que está obsoleta? ¿Muestra algo en pantalla? En los `option` tú quieres que muestre siempre la palabra `required`? ¿Dónde está el `select`  dentro del cual van esos `option`?

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que queires tener las dos columnas en el value del option.

Lo cual seria algo así:

`<option value='<?php echo $row["id_bl"].' '. $row["bl"]; ?>' required>Opcion 1</option>`

Puedes concatenar valores con el punto `.`, pero tener dos valores en una sola variable no es posible, una variable guarda un valor, si queires tener mas de uno utiliza un array.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
$var = $row["id_bl"]." ".$row["bl"];
```

Comment: Hola diego, quiero que se imprima uno abajo de otro.

Comment: Entonces usa un arreglo eso seria lo mas recomendado.

Comment: disculpa, soy bastante nuevo en esto, puedes darme una luz de como lo haria?